# Windows 10 Update Kills Network

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, auto-updates

Today my system got a Windows 10 Home update. The update killed networking and after it I could not connect to any computer or drive on the network. Rebooted a few times for good measure and nothing changed. Networking was still dead. Restored a backup from 20 days ago and networking is fine. After I let the update install again and networking died again. Now my machine is asking to update again and that would kill networking a third time.

**How do I cancel a pending Windows 10 Home update and blacklist not to get it again?**

Comment: What update?  Edit your question.  The only type of update you can block on Windows 10 are drivers.

Comment: There are a number of updates that appeared today *Jan 9, 2018*. They are from Windows Update, so Microsoft, not a third-party. Is there any way to identify them while they are pending? The backup has been restored, so obviously they are not installed right now.

Comment: I will come back after you indicate what those updates were.  I am trying to determine if you were installing driver updates (which would only be listed for you) or normal updates.  KB4056892 was released last week on patch Tuesday and MS didn’t release any out of band updates today.  Did you try uninstalling the updates one by one until your network connection returned?

Comment: Only updates released this week appear to be limited to .NET Framework security updates released oddly on Jan 7th.  I want to help, I have a 1709 installation, no updates today.

Comment: @Ramhound OK. Went through the update again. The build changed from 1703 to 1709 with 5 updates: KB4054517, KB4054022, KB4055237, KB4055994 and KB4057247. Only the first, third and forth can be uninstalled but the network remains hosed.

Comment: @Itai - Have you tried resetting the Network, from Start -> Settings -> Network & Internet -> Status -> network reset? Did you check whether the network started working properly after doing this! I too had problem with one of my home laptop when upgraded to version 1709!

Comment: **[KB4015547](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015547/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-update-kb4015547) isn't even a Windows 10 patch**  Why is none of that information in the question itself?

Comment: Must of mistyped a digit. Again, by the time I wrote the question, I had restored the backup, so these patches were not installed. It is a very long process to let the updates happen and restore so that I can have a usable system. The answer I am hoping for should not depend on which patch, the point is to know what to do when a patch hoses the system so that it does not happen with the same one again. Hopefully we don't need one way to avoid each different bad patch!

Comment: Same problem. A brand new Win10 PRO install worked fine for 2 days.  After an update, none of the networking is working. Hardware drivers are fine.  Devices are loaded and error free.  DHCP  times out. Its like the TCP or Winsock is logically disabled from connecting.All of the previous "fix your network" steps, like RESETing the network make no improvement. It has to be an update. My list of installed updates is similar to OP: KB4054517, KB4055994, KB4055237, KB4054022, KB4078408.  i cannot uninstall last two. Searching for clues on which one to remove first.

Comment: Other updates: Silverlight 5.1.50907.0, VC++ 201 redis KB2565063

Comment: I posted how I fixed it, but  DavidPostill jumped the shark and deleted my post before I could finish.  In summary: REFRESH worked. Took a long time, and it trashed my Activation Id. Details in deleted post.